# Second instance of mediawiki not loading

Tags: mediawiki

I have mediawiki on an internal server for one of my groups and it is running fine. I wanted to setup another wiki for a different internal group and I followed the instruction on how to do so on the following link http://sharkysoft.com/wiki/how_to_configure_multiple_MediaWiki_instances_on_a_single_host. The original install is on 192.168.10.25/mediawiki  I am trying to add 192.168.10.25/mediawiki/itwiki, but when I point to that url I get redirected to 192.168.10.25/mediawiki.

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS running apache2 and here is the apache.conf

```
Alias /mediawiki /var/lib/mediawiki

<Directory /var/lib/mediawiki/>
        Options +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        <IfVersion >= 2.3>
                Require all granted
        </IfVersion>
        <IfVersion < 2.3>
                order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </IfVersion>
</Directory>

# some directories must be protected
<Directory /var/lib/mediawiki/config>
        Options -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /var/lib/mediawiki/images>
        Options -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
        php_admin_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
<Directory /var/lib/mediawiki/upload>
        Options -FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    <IfModule mod_php5.c>
         php_admin_flag engine off
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: We need more information about your infrastructure. What OS / web server are you running? If you're running apache, what does the document root portion of your config look like?

Comment: Don't make it a subdirectory of your current wiki.

Comment: I have added additional information about the config in the body of the original question.

Answer (score -1):

Open the localsettings.php in the root folder of the second install of mediawiki search for $wgServer and change the URL to 192.168.10.25/mediawiki/itwiki